# In .NET Core, how can I increase the physical memory in use?

Tags: c#, .net-core, memory, ram

In order to test autoscaling of containers, I want to set the physical memory in use to certain levels.  It sounds simple enough, but the code that I'm running only sets the commit, rather than the physical memory in use.  AWS also doesn't see the memory increase.

I've tried two strategies, using *Marshal.AllocHGlobal*, and new *byte[...]*.

This is what the memory usage looks like before running:

[image]

And this is what it looks like while running (Using 5,000MB):

[image]

As you can see, the dotnet.exe process has a 5GB commit, but the physical memory doesn't go up.

Outputting the *PrivateMemorySize64* from the app shows:

```
Before:   9027584 
After: 5245612032
```

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace MemoryAbuser
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int MIN_MB_TO_USE = 5000;
        private const int DURATION_IN_SECONDS = 20;

        private static List<IntPtr> memoryPointers = new ();
        private static List<byte[]> usedMemory = new ();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetResources((ConsumptionStrategy)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsumptionStrategy), args[0]));
        }

        private static void SetResources(ConsumptionStrategy consumptionStrategy)
        {
            AllocateMemory(consumptionStrategy);
            Thread.Sleep(DURATION_IN_SECONDS * 1000);
            DeAllocateMemory();
        }

        static void AllocateMemory(ConsumptionStrategy strategy)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Memory consumption = {GetMemoryUsage()}");

            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            const int ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

            long minBytesToUse = ONE_MEGABYTE * (long)MIN_MB_TO_USE;

            while (GetMemoryUsage() < minBytesToUse)
            {
                switch (strategy)
                {
                    case ConsumptionStrategy.ByteArray: usedMemory.Add(new byte[ONE_MEGABYTE * 10]); break;
                    case ConsumptionStrategy.AllocHGlobal: memoryPointers.Add(Marshal.AllocHGlobal(ONE_MEGABYTE * 10)); break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Memory consumption = {GetMemoryUsage()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Seconds to allocate memory: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}");
        }

        static void DeAllocateMemory()
        {
            usedMemory.Clear();

            foreach (var memoryPointer in memoryPointers)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(memoryPointer);
            }

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }

        static long GetMemoryUsage()
        {
            using var proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            return proc.PrivateMemorySize64;
        }

        private enum ConsumptionStrategy
        {
            AllocHGlobal,
            ByteArray
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See e.g. https://aloiskraus.wordpress.com/2017/11/12/bringing-the-hardware-and-windows-to-its-limits/ for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered I have to actually use the RAM that has been allocated.  I managed to do that by setting a value for every 512th byte:

```
private static void CreateByteArray()
{
    var bytes = new byte[ONE_MEGABYTE * 10];
    _usedMemory.Add(bytes);
    for (var i = 0; i < ONE_MEGABYTE * 10; i += 512)
    {
        bytes[i] = 255;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, Windows memory manager is pretty smart nowadays.